# The void(), the comma operator (operator,) and the impossible (?) overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, void, comma-operator

Consider the following struct:

```
struct S {};
```

In C++14, the definition below is valid:

```
constexpr auto f() { return S{}, 'c'; }
```

As well as the following one:

```
constexpr auto f() { return S{}, void(); }
```

Now, consider the following, working snippet that involves the first of the two definitions:

```
#include<type_traits>

struct S {};

constexpr int operator,(S, char) { return 42; }
constexpr auto f() { return S{}, 'c'; }

int main() {
    constexpr int i{f()};
    static_assert(i == 42, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f()), int>::value, "!");
}
```

Speaking not so technically, the overload of the comma operator *intercepts* the couple `S{}, 'c'` and returns an integer, as correctly verified in the `main` function.

Now, suppose I want to do the same with the second definition of `f`:

```
constexpr auto f() { return S{}, void(); }
```

In this case, the comma operator should *intercept* the form `S{}, void()`.
Neither the following definition works (for obvious reasons):

```
constexpr int operator,(S, void) { return 42; }
```

Nor the one below (that would have worked in the previous case):

```
template<typename T> constexpr int operator,(S, T &&) { return 42; }
```

Is there any way to overload the comma operator so as to deal with `S{}, void()`?
Isn't it otherwise a lack in the standard, for it allows to use the comma operator that way, but doesn't give you the chance to overload the same operator (even if [the standard mentions that overloaded functions involving `S` are allowed](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#6))?

---

<sub>**Note**: this question is made for the sake of curiosity. Please, avoid comments like *do not do that* or *it is not good practice*. I'm not planning to do that in production environments. Thank you.</sub>

Comment: That's intriguingly crazy ;)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, I know. Standard guerrilla. I'm exploring the most obscure corners of the language. :-)

Comment: Changing the operator `,` to `+` gives an "argument may not have 'void' type" error.

Comment: This is really impossible. Casting to `void` is the standard trick to prevent people breaking your loops like `for(...;++it1, ++it2)` by overloading the comma operator for their iterator class.

Comment: @kennytm This is not a surprise indeed. The question is about `operator,`, not `operator+`.

Comment: @skypjack I don't see any different between them in terms of operator overloading :)

Comment: @kennytm Oh, ok, I see your point now. Well, anyway, note that `1 + void()` is not valid, `1, void()` is valid instead.

Comment: Interesting, I would like to know what's for the downvotes, it would help to improve the question at least...

Comment: @skypjack Yes, but some operators lose their special behavior when overloaded, e.g. `&&`, `||` are no longer short-circuiting.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The relevant clause for this is 13.3.1.2/9 [over.match.oper] in N4140:

> If the operator is the operator `,`, the unary operator `&`, or the operator `->`, and there are no viable functions,
>   then the operator is assumed to be the built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5.

As `void()` is never a valid function argument (see 5.2.2/7 [expr.call]), there never is a viable function and thus the built-in `,` will be used.

So no, what you are trying to do is not possible.

In fact, writing an iterator loop like this

```
for(...; ++it1, (void)++it2)
```

is a standard way to prevent users from breaking your code by overloading `,` for their iterator types by enforcing the built-in operator `,` to be used. (Note that I am not saying you need to do this in your everyday code. It very much depends on its actual use. This is standard library level of paranoid.)

---

Regarding the standard clause you linked:

> The meaning of the operators =, (unary) &, and , (comma), predefined for each type, can be changed for specific class and enumeration types **by defining operator functions that implement these operators**.

But such a function cannot be defined because, as I said above, `void()` is never a valid function argument.

Now whether or not this is an oversight/problem in the standard is open to debate.

Comment: Interesting use of `(void)` on the loop to avoid calling overloaded comma. Thanks for the tip!