# Why cast the result of pre-incrementation to void in comma separator context?

Tags: c++, casting, comma-operator

Looking at `std::for_each_n`'s [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n):

```
template<class InputIt, class Size, class UnaryFunction>
InputIt for_each_n(InputIt first, Size n, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for (Size i = 0; i < n; ++first, (void) ++i) {
        f(*first);
    }
    return first;
}
```

I noticed that the part where we typically see `i++` (or, the preferred `++i`) consists of two operations:

- `++first`
- `(void) ++i`

separated by a comma. While most of it makes sense, the `(void)` cast seems a little surprising to me. All I can guess is that there *could* be an overloaded `operator ,` that takes the deduced type of `InputIt` and `Size` which would result in some surprising side-effects. Could that be the reason? If yes, are we sure that cast to `void` solves that issue entirely?

Comment: related/good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514765/the-void-the-comma-operator-operator-and-the-impossible-overloading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The void(), the comma operator (operator,) and the impossible (?) overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514765/the-void-the-comma-operator-operator-and-the-impossible-overloading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could that be the reason?

Handling the evil overload of operator comma is indeed a good reason.

I don't see other (valid) reasons.

> If yes, are we sure that cast to `void` solves that issue entirely?

Yes, we cannot overload operator comma with `void` (neither with conversion to `void`).